# Random Rotation in Opposite Direction

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I set up random rotation in Geometry Nodes in a way that enables me to rotate the individual arrayed instance in opposite directions? Currently, the random value node only randomly rotates in the same direction.
[image: Random rotation in opposite directions][image: Current custom array node graph]

Current custom array node graph setup

[image]

Comment: did you try set min to -1?

Comment: You mean on the Random Value node? Yeah, but that just expands the range in the opposite direction. It still rotates all of the instances in the same direction. I want to rotate the individual instances in random opposite directions, as shown in the gif.

Comment: ok pls provide blend file so we can see what we are doing, thx

Comment: Just included the file in the post. Thank you.

Comment: I essentially want to build a "smart array" that will let me place things on a shelf but allow me to rotate (on z) the instances and position (on x & y) in random directions, instead of in a single direction, so it breaks up that CGI look where it's all perfectly aligned and spaced apart.

Comment: Sorry, to help you I need to understand what you mean by saying "the same direction"... what I see in the animation above is cubes 1, 3 and 4 rotating clockwise, 2 and 5 counter-clockwise - and not the same angle. To me this is not the same direction... It only surprises me if the values shown in the screenshot do this, because they only generate positive values so it would be normal that they rotate in the same direction. Anyway, with your file I tried setting Min/Max to -Pi and Pi for more variation and they rotate in different directions, depending on the seed more or less different.

Comment: By the way, since you are generating random float values for the rotation, is there a special reason you have set the _Switch_ node to _Vector_? Now you plug a float value in a vector input, get a vector output which you then plug in a float input... does not really make sense...?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

If you want to guarantee some minimal rotation / angular velocity, but alternate direction:

[image]

[image]

If you want to randomize rotation axis:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as i wrote in comments, just give in min -1 and e.g. choose seed 2. Then both directions will be seen. Looks like you just tested only with seed 0.

also i would recommend using the nodes like this:

[image]

so it is clear that you switch really a vector here.

Comment: Yeah, the seed is not the best for this small group... changing it would have helped him to see it actually works. Or maybe instead of using 5 instances something like 20... more objects, more chances to get opposite directions.